# Opensource ERP that allows on-premise commerical use

Tags: open-source, resource-management

Looking for an ERP Solution that is opensource. This will be deployed **internally** for **commercial** use.

I may extend the product, so extensible architecture will be nice. Extensible via REST or plugin in language like Java or Python will do.

It will be good if the product is supported On Linux.
It will be good if the it runs with any free database (like PostgreSQL).

(I did find some recommendations in SO.  Hoping to move some of them here).

Answer (score 2):

Odoo (formerly OpenERP)][1](https://www.odoo.com/page/about-us) was started in 2005. Odoo thrives in a unique and fully open ecosystem combining the resources of its open source community, partners’ network and resellers.

Language is Python. 
[Licensing](https://www.odoo.com/page/legal) is GNU Affero General Public License (also known as AGPLv3)